# How do cakePHP model functions work?

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-model

This is the example from the cookbook:

```
class IngredientsController extends AppController {

    public function index() {
        //grab all ingredients and pass it to the view:
        $ingredients = $this->Ingredient->find('all');
        $this->set('ingredients', $ingredients);
    }
```

So it looks like we're using `find('all')` and returning all of them to the index. I figure we can also create a method called `frenchIngredients()` that would return all the french ingredients.

My question is do I have to create a separate function for every find condition I want to have for the Controller?

I'm really new to cakePHP, so maybe I just don't understand how this is supposed to work, but the way I'm seeing it, I'm going to have to create large numbers of functions and/or views just to account for changes in find conditions.

Does cakePHP suck that bad or am I missing something? I thought it would make my PHP OOP easier, but really it just seems like a lot of overhead to convert something working into something I have no idea how to work.

Comment: I am with you. I wonder the same. Model stuff should be inside the model and not in every controller. If I change a field in my table, it is suppose that I should only make changes at my model, not at every find I did at any of my controllers... Something is wrong in here.

Answer (score 0):

Cake has a lot of "magic" functions. You can do `findBy<columName>` or even `findAllBy<columName>`. You can also chain the column names like `findBy<colum1>And<colum2>`.

I suggest you read their [cook book article on models](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html). The cook book is a really great way to start and have information about what the framework can do for you. If you want more information on a function you can always go peek in their [api](http://api21.cakephp.org/) which is more complete.

Answer (score 0):

In any frameworks such as ZF and Codeigniter , I think this is actually the process of building your model.

In your example in CakePHP, if you created it with Bakery then you already have this functionality. There are lots of database functions which is included in every model but your job is to extend it. Not all things is already made in your model.

The only thing I can suggest is to be sure and make sure not to be redundant on building Model methods. If you think "freshIngredients" will be the same with other models you can implement a base Model and extend it to your new models. Like creating a Base model with method of "newItems" which will return newly added items or in your part it's ingredients.

Answer (score 0):

There is happily no need to create a function for each simple conditional find.

The `find` function takes more than one argument (see the doc in [Retrieving Your Data](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#find)) and one of its parameters are the find conditions.

Do you want to fetch only the french ingredients ? Let's say you have categories for the ingredients, and that the 'french ingredient' category has the ID 2, you would do it like this:

```
$this->Ingredient->find('all', array('conditions' => array('category_id' => 2)));
```

And conditions passed to `find` can be [much more complex](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html#complex-find-conditions) than this simple example.

But off course, it often makes sense to create functions in models when you have some more complex logic than a simple find query.

Comment: I think Drew is wondering why this calls are done from the controller if it is suppose to be done at the model. And as he wants to do them on the model, he is asking why should we create a function for each condition. I wonder the same... If I change a field in my table, it is suppose that I should only make changes at my model, not at every `find` I did at any of my controllers...

Comment: Let's say you want to display the value from a field called 'username' in a 'users' table. You would create an action in a controller that would ask a User model to return the username.
I don't see the real benefit to wrap this kind of call in a function that you would probably call `getUsername()`. Well, the benefit would be that you could rename the database field name, but why would you do it ?

Comment: And actually the same question could apply if you would like to rename your `getUsername()` function: you would have to update some controllers code. And I don't see why I would more likely rename the databse field than the method name.

Comment: As far as I know, the MVC pattern try to separate as much as possible the 3 layers. So if one day i decide to change my Users table for a textfile or anything else, I would only have to change the model at my system. Controllers will still receiving the exactly same data and we only had to change the model functions. If we start using the find methods at our controller, we break this concept.

Comment: No, because you could still ask for the 'username', regardless of whether the information comes from a database or a text file, which you are right, doesn't concern the controller at all. And if you do need to replace 'username' by 'my_new_username_field', you could do it at the model level by using model callbacks. But in Cake default is to use the same names than the real database field names, which IMHO makes sense because it is the most common case.

Comment: Cake is built to work with a database. Yes in pure mvc it should be separated but cakePHP is a precise case of mvc using a database and more precisely with column with precise names.